# Update paragraph using lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

I'm trying to improve the filtering code I have for filtering input.

The input I have looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Page 1</p>
    <p style="display: none">Pagebreak</p>
    <p>Page 2</p>
    <p style="display: none">Pagebreak</p>
    <p>Page 3</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use a filter like this in order to replace words "Pagebreak" with actual docx pagebreak XML piece:

```
function Para (el)
  -- Turning paragraphs which contain nothing but a Pagebreak word
  -- into line breaks.
  if #el.content == 1 and el.content[1].text == "Pagebreak" then
    return pandoc.RawBlock('openxml', '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>')
  end
end

return {
  {Para = Para}
}
```

I control the input HTML, and would like to simplify it by removing `<p style="display: none">Pagebreak</p>` in favor of an attribute on regular paragraph. What I'd like to have is this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Page 1</p>
    <p class="pageBreak">Page 2</p>
    <p class="pageBreak">Page 3</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**What lua code should I write to achieve this?**

From the "[Creating a handout from a paper](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#creating-a-handout-from-a-paper)" example I see that it's possible to inspect the classes of incoming elements. But how do I modify the existing paragraph to have a page break in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, pandoc's document model currently [doesn't support attributes on paragraphs](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684). However, you can use a `div` instead:

```
<div class="pageBreak">Page 3</div>
```

I see you've already found the [open issue about page breaks](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1934)